# How do I create a table for haml using loop directly in ruby file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, haml

I'm trying to create a table that shows the contents of a zip file like this:

```
Name      Size
asdf1.jpg 100KB
asdf2.jpg 200KB
asdf3.jpg 300KB
```

And my code is here (actually, I copied it from ZipRuby's README):

```
#myapp.rb
post 'checkfile/?' do
    Zip::Archive.open('zip_file.zip') do |ar|
        n = ar.num_files 

        n.times do |i|
            entry_name = ar.get_name(i) # get entry name from archive

            # open entry
            ar.fopen(entry_name) do |f| # or ar.fopen(i) do |f|
                $name = f.name           # name of the file
                $size = f.size           # size of file (uncompressed)
                $comp_size = f.comp_size # size of file (compressed)
                content = f.read # read entry content
            end
        end
        # Zip::Archive includes Enumerable
        entry_names = ar.map do |f|
            f.name
        end
    end
    haml :checkresult
end
```

And my haml code:

```
-# checkresult.haml
%table
%thead
    %tr
        %th Name
        %th Size
%tbody
    %tr
        -# I want to show files in zip here
```

Sorry for poor English, and bad title.
(Using Sinatra v1.4.6 (with Puma.))

Comment: Are you sure you are using `Ruby on Rails`?  Can you confirm the web framework your are using?

Comment: Using Sinatra v1.4.6 (with Puma.) Thanks for comments! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the data for `haml` rendering by assigning values to instance variables in your Sinatra app.   Please go through [this tutorial](http://blog.maxaller.name/2010/01/a-brief-introduction-to-ruby-sinatra-and-haml/).

You need to make some changes to `myapp.rb` as indicated below.  We define `@result` array to collect results

```
# myapp.rb
post 'checkfile/?' do

    @result = []  # this will hold results.

    Zip::Archive.open('zip_file.zip') do |ar|
        ar.each do |f|
            @result << [f.name, f.size, f.comp_size]
        end
    end

    haml :checkresult
end
```

You will need update your haml file to look like below - `table` tag added, iterator added to iterate over results and emit `td`

```
-# checkresult.haml
%table
%thead
    %tr
        %th Name
        %th Size
        %th Compressed size
%tbody
    %table
        - @result.each do |i|
            %tr
                %td= i[0]
                %td= i[1]
                %td= i[2]
```

PS: I could not install ZipRuby on my Windows machine, so that part of code above is bit of guess work based on [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/winebarrel/zip-ruby/wiki/Home) - hope you get the idea of what has to be done.